# Need help plotting graphs in tkinter using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a program using `matplotlib` and `tkinter` to plot graphs through a GUI. Everything works as planned, except after I input the `x` and `y` variables, the graph plotted is an exact x=y line except the numbers on the axes are in the order they are inputted in.

[image]

Here is the code:

I've already tried using `axis` command from `matplotlib` but it didn't work.

```
x=[]
y=[]

enterx = ttk.Entry(self)
enterx.pack()
enterx.insert(0,"X")
entery = ttk.Entry(self)
entery.pack()
entery.insert(0,"Y")

def creategraph(self,parent,x,y,enterx,entery):
    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    textx = enterx.get()
    texty = entery.get()
    x=textx.split(",")
    y=texty.split(",")
    a.plot(x,y)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
    canvas.draw()
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas,self)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

The code does not include `tkinter` window initialization or widgets. I thought it would plot a line with evenly spaced numbers on the axes, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the values you are plotting are strings and hence the order is not based on numerics. Following is one solution: Convert your string values to `int` (integer) type using `map`. The modified lines of code are marked by a comment.

---

```
def creategraph(self,parent,x,y,enterx,entery):
    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    textx = enterx.get()
    texty = entery.get()
    x=list(map(int, textx.split(","))) # <---- Convert strings to int 
    y=list(map(int, texty.split(","))) # <---- Convert strings to int 
    a.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually really helped me with my project, didn't think I'd even get a response. I just kind of feel a little stupid that I didn't convert to integers.

Comment: You are welcome